# Is it acceptable to copy my question(s) from Draw3Cards to Board & Card Games?

Tags: discussion

[Draw3Cards](http://draw3cards.com/) is a SE 1.0 site for MtG.  I am not active there anymore, but I have asked a couple questions there that I believe would be beneficial to have asked here.  Obviously, copying every non-duplicate question from there seems unethical so I only want to ask *my* questions here.  Would this be acceptable?

Answer (score 2):

There are no plans to wholesale import data from SE1 sites anymore.

That said, there is nothing stopping you from asking those questions here.

Comment: I am aware that there are no plans to import this data.  My main concern was if this kind of activity would be considered reputation farming or some other heinous act.

Answer (score 1):

As the owner of Draw3Cards, I can say that there's nothing in our TOS to stop you from doing that. I don't know about the ethics of Board Games or SE in general though - this could be considered rep farming.

Can I ask *why* you would want to do this? Were the questions not answered properly on D3C? Or are you just trying to "artificially boost" the content in Boardgames SE?

I won't complain, no matter how you do this.

One thing though - right now, the way I see it, Magic is the #1 game tag on Boardgames, way past any other tag. I and others strongly think that there is room for a dedicated Magic SE site. If you agree, I think a better move would be to support the proposal [for a dedicated site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4082/magic-the-gathering), and perhaps wait until it opens and ask your questions there. I'm not sure if Boardgames is sustainable or not without the Magic content - but it is my opinion that Magic deserves a dedicated SE nonetheless, even if this means a substanial dilution of Boardgames SE.

Comment: Oh, and btw - why did you leave D3C in the first place?

Comment: The question was answered properly on D3C (I answered it myself) and I am not trying to artificially boost my rep here.  The question simply addresses a mechanic that I believe is frequently overlooked and I want to spread this information as much as possible. I am already committed to the MTG proposal, but there are other places for that discussion.  I "left" D3C because I am hoping the MTG proposal moves into beta soon....ish.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot - well, if you already support that proposal ... which seems to be under way, I don't think you should start adding a bunch of questions here from D3C, only to migrate them later. But then again, migrating is relatively easy within in SE, so maybe it's not such a big deal. The larger question is will all Magic questions be migrated to Magic SE from Boardgames.

Comment: I thought about that, but it might be a while.  I only *asked* 2 questions on D3C and this is the only one I feel needs to be spread as far and wide as possible.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot - well, if it's only 1-2 questions, I really don't see any problem in re-asking them, especially if you feel they're important.

Answer (score 0):

The only issue I can think of is that it will set a precedent for that behavior. While you happen to be the person who asked those questions (or *so you say<sup>1</sup>*...), what's to prevent me or another user with nefarious rep-farming intent from going and asking every question that's been posted on Draw 3 Cards?

I couldn't actually find anything about Draw3Cards' Terms of Service - IANAL, but it might not actually be legal to duplicate that content here.  In contrast, at the bottom of all SE pages there's the following blurb:

> user contributions licensed under [cc-wiki](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/) with [attribution required](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)

Given that it's entirely unrelated to Stack Exchange, if it does happen to be legal, the worst that can be said is that it'll hurt D3C in it's page ranking (in that the exact same content on D3C will be competing with SE).

<sub>[1]: I actually know @OrigamiRobot in real life, he's the person who asked those questions on D3C.</sub>